# Mercurial update-pull vs commit

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I'm having a hard time understanding a scenario under mercurial.

Assuming i have 2 users working on the same repository. Assuming the repo is called 'Test' and it currently has files: a.txt & b.txt (both text files are currently empty with no text in them)

This is what happened:

### User 1:

Modify a.txt with the sentence "Line 1"
Commit the code to the local repo (No push command issued)

### User 2:

Modify b.txt with the sentence "Line 1"
Commits the code to the local repo
Issues a push command as well

### User 1:

Issues a pull command
Issues an update command

RESULT: In the working directory of User 1, the file a.txt no longer contains the sentence  "Line 1" and file b.txt contains the changes of User 2. Where did the initial changes of a.txt go? overwritten? I can see them in the history logs (using TortoiseHG) but these changes aren't at the tip anymore.

What exactly happened here? My understanding is the following: When User 1 issues a pull, the changes on his local repo should somehow merge the changes coming in from User 2 with what User 1 already committed.

Can you tell me where my assumptions/understanding is wrong? If the solution to the problem above is about proper sequence of commit/push/update/pull then what's the suggested sequence of actions for an environment of multiple developers on the same code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When **User1** pulls, the changeset of **User2** is put at the tip of the repo. When he issues the `hg update` command, Mercurial updates to the most recent tip of the current branch, which is **User2**'s changeset, without **User1**'s modifications.

**User1** now has two heads on his repo, his own changeset and **User2**'s changeset. To obtain a combination of both changeset, he has to specifically merge the two heads, by issuing a `hg merge` command, which will merge the two heads of the current branch. Do not forget to commit the merged changeset, too.

The merge operation is not done automatically, Mercurial won't make decisions for you. You may want to do other things with your changeset before pushing it.

For example, a prettier alternative to this merge operation, is to use the Rebase extension, to put both changesets sequentially, and issue this command

```
hg rebase -s <User1-revision> -d <User2-revision>
hg update
```

You are basically reordering the changesets as if the modifications of **User1** were made after the modifications of **User2**, which are already made public and part of the repo, by *rebasing* them on the tip. This alternative works well if **User1**'s changeset is not yet pushed to the public.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it makes sense. I'm using TortoiseHG and there wasn't a "clear" indication that im running with 2 heads. I had to issue the hg head comman to visually see that. Im pretty sure TortoiseHG is telling me about the 2 heads but i can't seem to figure out where...

Comment: Having more than one head is not unusual, so there are no warning, but you can see the split in the graph of TortoiseHg. At the push, however, you will get a warning, and Mercurial will block the operation until you solve the multiple heads issue.

Comment: Thank you Vince for your valuable input. Just as an FYI, i merged the two heads and i was able to continue my work normally. Appreciate the help